# Find path with minimum cost and maximum length given a maximum cost

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm searching for an algorithm to find a path between two nodes with minimum cost and maximum length given a maximum cost in an undirected weighted complete graph. Weights are non negative.

As I stand now I'm using DFS, and it's pretty slow (high number of nodes and maximum length too). I already discard all the impossible nodes in every iteration of the DFS.

Could someone point me to a known algorithm for better handling of this problem?

To clarify: ideally the algorithm should search for the path of minimum cost, but is allowed to add cost if this means visiting more nodes. It should end when it concludes that it's impossible to reach more than n nodes without crossing the cost limit and it's impossible to reach n nodes with less cost.

**Update**

Example of a graph. We have to go from A to B. Cost limit is set to 5:

[image: graph]
This path (in red) is ok, but the algorithm should continue searching for better solutions

[image]

This is better because although the cost is increased to 4, it contains 1 more node

[image]

Here the path contains 3 nodes so it's a lot better than before and the cost is an acceptable 5

[image]

Finally this solution is even better because the path also contains 3 nodes but with cost 4, with is less than before.

[image]

Hope images explain better than text

Comment: Ah, I misread. Why not switch to a BFS (breadth first) and discard paths above the cost threshold? Since you'll (I think) need to visit *all paths* under the cost threshold to find the "maximum length" anyway.

Comment: I already discard all the impossible nodes in every iteration of the DFS. Plus there are a LOT of nodes and DFS is better at memory.

Comment: Omg why the downvotes. My question is sincere. Maybe it's difficult to read..?

Comment: May the path visit a node more than once? If so, may it reuse an edge?

Comment: @Beta No. I should avoid repeating nodes in the path.

Comment: The way you've phrased your objective function is unclear to me. Do you mean that you want to find the maximum-length path between two nodes whose cost is less than a given value, and if there's a tie among those paths then output the one with minimum cost?

Comment: @jacobm The objective is to find the maximum number of nodes I can visit in the path given a fixed cost. Then ensure I'm using a minimal cost path to visit them. So yes, I suppose..

Comment: This is a slight variation on the longest path problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem Unfortunately it's known to be NP-hard.

Comment: This problem looks like [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Quote from wiki -  _Given a set of items, each with a mass and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible_.Weight limit=cost limit, value=number of visited nodes. Values are all edges (i,j) where both i,j!=source,target. Solution looks like-`min_edge(s,others)+knapsack(all edges besides edges starting on s or t)+min_edge(t,others)`.Boundary case -edge `(source,target)`.

Comment: @Baurzhan But the weights are on the edges so every "item" I put on the "Knapsack" allows me to put a totally different set of items. I don't think this is the Knapsack problem but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Inuart, you are right. Knapsack doesn't care about order of elements but here it's important - adjacent items in knapsack should be connected. So, it isn't the correct solution(

Comment: Maybe I should ask this in cstheory

Comment: @jacobm no this problem has a DP solution that is polynomial.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Suppose you have a polynomial-time algorithm to solve OP's problem. Then pass in an arbitrary graph and a cost budget of infinity (or some other number larger than the max possible path weight, e.g. the sum of all edge weights). Now your poly-time algorithm returns a path of maximal length (and incidentally lowest cost), thereby solving the longest-path problem in poly time -- a contradiction. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Idea 1:**

In my opinion your problem is a variation of the [pareto optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) shortest path search problem. Because you refer to 2 different optimality metrics:

1. Longest Path by edge count
2. Shortest Path by edge weight

Of course some side constraints just make the problem more easy to calculate.

You have to implement a multi criteria dijkstra for pareto optimal results. I found two promising paper in english for this problem:

- A multicriteria Pareto-optimal path algorithm
- On a multicriteria shortest path problem

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the pdf files for those papers and the papers I read before where in german :(
Nevertheless this should be your entry point and will lead you to an algorithm to solve your problem nice and smoothly.

**Idea 2:**

Another way to solve this problem could lie in the calculation of [hamilton path](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianPath.html), because the longest path in a complete graph is indeed the hamilton path. After calculation of all such path you still have to find the one with the smallest total edge weight cost. This scenario is useful if the length of the path is in every case more relevant than the cost.

**Idea 3:**

If the cost of the edges is the more important fact you should calculate all paths between those two nodes of a given maximum length and search for the one with the most used edges.

**Conclusion:**

I think the best results will be obtained by using idea 1. But I didn't know your scenario to well, therefore the other ideas might be an option two.

Comment: Also, I found
http://www.univ-valenciennes.fr/ROI/WP/download/2004/11-2004.pdf
and
http://dlibra.bu.uz.zgora.pl/Content/9346/11tarapata.pdf

Comment: Hm, it seems they translated it :D found those two paper: https://www.algo.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Group_ALGO/pdf/publications/Mueller-HannemannSchneeAtmos_2004.pdf
 ; http://www.coga.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/i26/download/AG_DiskAlg/FG_KombOptGraphAlg/paper/2008/DisserMullerHannemannEtal2008.pdf

Comment: 2 out of 4 links are broken.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes, sorry for the inconvenience, already 5 years since they where posted. I have no idea what the actual papers where.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can formulated as Multi-objective Constraint Satisfaction Problem with priority:

- First, solution must satisfy the constraint about maximum cost.
- Next, solution must has maximum number of nodes (1st objective).
- Finally, solution must has minimum cost (2st objective).

This problem is NP-hard. So, there isn't exact polynomial time algorithm for this problem. But a simple local search algorithm may help you:

- First, use Dijkstra algorithm to find minimum cost path, called P. If the cost is bigger than maximum cost, there isn't solution satisfy constraint.
- Next, try add more nodes to P by using 2 move operators:

  - Insert: select a node outside P and insert in best position in P.
  - Replace: select a node outside P and replace a node inside P (when can't use insert operator).
- Finally, try reduce cost by using replace operator.

Comment: how do I find the "best position" to insert in P?

Comment: In local search, the "best move" depend on how you define, it's usually a heuristic evaluation. I'll choose position such that the cost of new path is minimal.