# Directed graph theory algorithm with specified start and end nodes which finds a path that visits the most nodes with the least weight

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, traveling-salesman

There is a starting point an ending point in the **directional graph**. Also there are discrete nodes which aren't connected to the start and/or end nodes. I want to find a path that visits most of the nodes, compared to other branches, that starts and ends in the specified nodes with the least weight.

Let's say a person traverses the graph. Starting node is **their home at 10 AM** and ending node is **their home at 7 PM**. They can visit the node **doing chores at 11 am** and then visit directly the end node or they can visit also some other nodes after chores and go to the end node.

In my opinion it is similar to TSP but in TSP you must strictly visit all the nodes and also it isn't directed. In my problem I need to find a branch that starts and ends in specified nodes. My first instinct was brute forcing but I guess there is a better algorithm which I can investigate further.

Edit: There is no weight restriction, however if there are two or more paths with the same node counts, I would rather picking the less weighted one. Main filter is most nodes, second filter is least weight.

Comment: I think you need to calculate the cost of reaching home from each node. This can be done with a simple BFS. Then using DFS and backtracking you can exhaust all paths while keeping tabs on way back home by the cost that you calculated previously.

Comment: There are a few ambiguities in the question. Do you have a budget? For instance, you have a total maximum weight W, and you want to visit as many nodes as you can without accumulating more than W in weight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find path with minimum cost and maximum length given a maximum cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861817/find-path-with-minimum-cost-and-maximum-length-given-a-maximum-cost)

Comment: First you need to decide on a concrete measure to maximise or minimise (e.g., minimise the total weight of visited nodes on a path beginning at A and ending at B). If the graph is a DAG (free of cycles), this can be solved in linear time (google Critical Path algorithm). If there are cycles the problem is NP-complete, so some kind of brute force is necessary for optimal solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP-hard, and thus no feasible algorithm for all inputs exists.

Your best bet is likely to encode your problem in a SAT solver like z3.